# Can we track if a video is being played or is ended in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, iframe

Is it possible to check if a video inside an Iframe is being played or is finished,

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="home-content-slider">
        <div class="home-content-inner">
            <iframe id="vid1" src="<%= post %>" width="" height="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is an iframe, i just want to trigger an event as soon as the video ends, is it possible through Jquery?

Answer (score 0):

iFrames were initially not protected against communication between window elements, but that eventually became a big security concern.  The response was to isolate the window objects between iFrame and primary windows in sandboxes.

As a result, you can't directly probe the status of what's going on inside the iFrame, but you can communicate from the iFrame to the top frame using `postMessage`, with reasonably broad adoption (https://caniuse.com/#search=postmessage).

https://davidwalsh.name/window-postmessage

The sender (your iframe) uses `postMessage` to send status updates, and your top window listens for an event called `message` to receive the messages.